# Gmailapp is sending double emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that sends me emails at various points. The two emails shown below are each getting sent twice, but none of the other emails being sent in this script have this problem. I can't figure out why. It's not in any kind of loop or anything that could make the code run twice. In addition, as you can see here there's a flag that ought to prevent this because status is set to "awaiting approval" right before the email gets sent, so if the code is executing twice it should get caught in the first IF condition.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
var currentRow = ss.getCurrentCell().getRow(); //this is the row the user is in
  

function addEvent() { 
  var status = ss.getSheetValues(lastRow, 45, 1, 1).toString();
  if (status == "emails sent" || status == "awaiting approval") {return;}

  //if not approved yet ask for approval
  var approved = ss.getSheetValues(lastRow, 2, 1, 1);
  if (approved == "No" & status == "") { 
    
    ss.getRange(currentRow, 45).setValue("awaiting approval");
     
    var approvalBody = "stuff";

//THESE TWO EMAILS ARE GETTING SENT OUT TWICE EACH
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      "admins@baltimoretherapycenter.com", 
      "New client approval needed.", 
      approvalBody
    );

    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      "raffi@xxxx.com", 
      "New client approval needed.", 
      approvalBody, 
      {from:'info@xxxx.com', name:"Approverizer"}
    );

    return;
  } //end request approval sequence
```

Comment: Do you not see the to GmailApp.sendEmail() commands?

Comment: Both raffi@ and admins@ are getting double emails. I will make this clearer in the post.

Comment: currentRow and lastRow undefined.  Provide [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me. :-)
I am putting in the full code. I thought it might be easier if I cut it down. I will mark the spot after which I am pretty sure it's irrelevant.

Comment: That looks like the beginning of the process of making a [mcve].  Now you need to remove all of the unnecessary stuff that has nothing to do with the question but still reproduces the problem.  Then post that.

Comment: Ok, I think I got the minimal reproducible example now! 
I actually tried reproducing it myself and in the course of this discovered the following: when I send to two email addresses, both addresses get double emails. When I took out the sending to admins@, I only received one email. ???

Comment: That is by far the greatest thing that I discovered about  make a [mcve],  It often leads me to the point of not needing to ask a question in the first place which is preferable to me.

Comment: That makes sense. But I still have no idea why it sends out 2 doubles when I try to send to 2 addresses... ?